# How to train an ML again?

Tags: swift, createml

After i created MLImageClassifierBuilder() in playground and saved ML model, it saved as "ImageClassifier.mlmodel" on desktop. But how to open that file in playground again?

Answer (score 0):

[You need to use it "as is" and load it in your project.](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5653-create-ml-tutorial-getting-started)

You cannot edit it after it was generated, you can only recreate it again with the new input.